# Retrieving credentials from multiple tables in ASP

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to have a login page that'll take the email and password from 2 different tables in the same database. I have a `student_regis` and a `Uni_regis` table and these both cannot be combined in the same table since during registration there are different not null values for both the tables.

I've tried using UNION but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = select count(*) 
                    from student_regis 
                    where email='" + mail.Text + "' and password='" + password.Text + "' 
                    union 
                    select count(*) 
                    from student_regis 
                    where email = '" + mail.Text + "' and password = '" + password.Text + "';

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, scon);

    String output = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    if (output == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Home_page.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Username or password was wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question has a lot of issues. What does "doesn't work" mean? Is it not working because there is an error? Is it not working because your query doesn't return the desired output? There are many out-of-the box authentication mechanisms for asp.net, maybe you should look into it and let asp.net handle it for you.

Comment: If you're going to learn....might as well learn the right way. This code is incredibly insecure. Passwords should not be stored in the database as plain text, they should be one way hashed and salted. That way they're irreversible without a lot of brute force if someone were to steal the password hashes. You also shouldn't form your SQL queries via string concatenation - that's [incredibly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yes I am not able to reach my desired outcome of getting user credentials from the tables. I think the problem is in the sql statement and union doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @mason yes I have hashed out the password in the registration screen. and thanks for the advise, will remove concatenations.

Comment: If you hashed out the password...then why are you taking user input from the text box and comparing that to what you have stored in the database without having hashed it to match?

Comment: Note also that `union` will de-duplicate (as opposed to `union all`). But you probably want something more along the lines of `select count(*) from (select 1 as x from student_regis where email = @email and passwordHash = @hash union all select 1 as x from ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try, make two queries, one for student and another to 'uni', and make one

```
else if (output2 == "1")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Home_page.aspx");
}
```